# Add support to Stack Overflow for highlighting Nim code

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

The Nim language (tag [nim-lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nim-lang)) is [supported in highlight.js](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/master/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md), but it is not yet supported on Stack Overflow: `hljs.registerLanguage('nim', ...` is not present in the [highlight.js loader](https://dev.sstatic.net/js/highlightjs-loader.en.js). See the [reference question on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109).

Comment: Tons of languages are supported by highlight.js but not by SO, and Nim only has 400 questions here. Could you explain why this one should get priority over supporting other languages with more questions?

Comment: Most likely other languages should indeed have priority over this, I am not stating any priority with this request. I am aware of the fact that Nim has very few questions in SO, since the forum (https://forum.nim-lang.org/) is mostly used for questions. I personally think Nim community would benefit from an increased SO usage and I expect that this will happen soon enough given the sustained growth of the community. Feel free to evaluate this feature request with the appropriate priority and also to let me know if this is not the appropriate channel for such a feature request.

Comment: @pietroppeter There is a Tampermonky script to add support for extra languages that you could use if seeing Nim higlighted would be of benefit to just yourself. I'm sure it could easily be converted into a Chrome plugin as well if someone had the time.  It's also possible communities without languages supported by SO could encourage the use of such plugins to improve their individual SO experiences...

Comment: Thanks that is good to know, I will check it out!

Comment: @josh-goebel I was not able to find any Tampermonkey script to do what you suggest. I guess my google-fu is not up to the task!

Comment: @pietroppeter https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/354427/853855

Comment: Thanks, right under my nose!

Comment: Cross-site duplicate (MSE, posted two days prior): *[Add syntax highlighting support for Nim](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355491/add-syntax-highlighting-support-for-nim)*